# A batch that cout the number of occurrences

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, grep, wc

I've to extract the number of words using each letter of the alphabet from A to Z. The script that i've to create create take as parameter the name of the dictionary file to analyze and will be used like this ./langstat.sh dico.txt

I tried few things like this :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cat ~/dico.txt | grep -o A | wc -l
```

The problem is that it gives me the number of A into all the file, but I want to know only the number of word having a A into.

Could you give me a hand please?

Comment: `grep -ci A ~/dico.txt`. See also: `fold -w1 ~/dico.txt | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this instead:

```
for c in {A..Z}; do
  echo -n "$c: "
  tr ' ' '\n' < dico.txt | grep $c | wc -l
done
```

It works as follows: The for loop runs through each character from A to Z. `tr` replaces all spaces with newlines, so every word has its own line. Then `grep` searches for the character in the word an prints it if the character is found. `wc` counts those lines.

Comment: I would like to sort those informations, for exemple there are more K than X so i would like to see C:38456 E:36756 ... K:456 X:326.

Comment: @JulienS add `| sort -rk2` after `done`. It sort the second field descending.

Comment: That works for me: `for c in {A..Z}; do   echo -n "$c: ";   tr ' ' '\n' < dico.txt | grep $c | wc -l; done | sort -rk2`

Answer (score 0):

Is it helps?

```
#!/bin/bash
tr ' ' '\n' < "$1" | sort -u > my.tmp
for letter in {A..Z}
do
    printf "Words with %c : " $letter
    grep -iwc "\w*$letter\w*" my.tmp
    echo
done
rm my.tmp
```

Comment: Thank's a lot ! I'm a rookie on Unix and this kind of fast answer saves me a lot resarches. I can continue my tutorial thank's to you !